# node.js Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's the code that the error is in, the error is on the last line that you see here and i'm not sure how to solve it,
I'm pretty new to all of this, so some advice would be useful. I need to solve this issue as quick as possible as we are using this bot as a moderation tool in one of my Discord servers. Thank you all!

```
   }
    
    if (command === "slap") {
         const options = [
             "https://tenor.com/view/no-angry-anime-slap-gif-7355956",
             "https://tenor.com/view/when-you-cant-accept-reality-slap-anime-gif-14694312",
             "https://tenor.com/view/anime-slap-slap-in-the-face-smash-gif-17314633"
        ]
        if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + " slapped " + message.mentions.users.first().username)
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You have to mention a user to slap")
        }
    }
        if (command === "shutdown") {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "shutdown") { 
        }
        message.channel.send("Shutting down...").then(() => {
            bot.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `}` and `)` after the `bot.destroy()` call. Check that you have a closing parenthesis `)` for each opening parenthesis `(`, and a closing bracket `}` for each opening bracket `{`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a closing `)` and `}`, this is easier to see with formatting:

```js
if (command === "slap") {
  const options = [
    "https://tenor.com/view/no-angry-anime-slap-gif-7355956",
    "https://tenor.com/view/when-you-cant-accept-reality-slap-anime-gif-14694312",
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-slap-slap-in-the-face-smash-gif-17314633"
  ]
  if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
    message.channel.send(message.author.username + " slapped " + message.mentions.users.first().username)
  } else {
    message.channel.send("You have to mention a user to slap")
  }
}
if (command === "shutdown") {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "shutdown") { 

  }
  message.channel.send("Shutting down...").then(() => {
    bot.destroy();
  })
}
```